Conda build install shared libraries in env
I have a python library in C++ that I can install via pip provided all libraries are installed on the system. I want to make it easier for users so I want a conda package that would also install the libraries required by my library to run : libblas, liblapack in particular.
I can build the package with conda build, and I do get a functional library. However, it does not ship with the required libraries (libblas, liblapack). So if I install the *.tar.bz2 in an environment without those libraries, my library will not work.
How to get my library to also automatically install  the required libraries (libblas and liblapack) in the env ?
Here is the (relevant part) of the meta.yaml file :
requirements:
  build:
    - cmake>=3.14
    - make 
    - {{compiler('cxx')}}
    - libblas
    - liblapack
    - pybind11
  host:
    - pip
    - python
    - libblas
    - liblapack
    - pybind11
  run:
    - python
    - libblas
    - liblapack
    - pybind11



Could you show how you do the linking/header inclusion of libblas/liblapack to your library within e.g., setup.py? Do you hardcode the paths to the libraries or have a method of automatically finding the correct paths?

The linking is done by the compiler as setup.py calls cmake.
In CMakeLists.txt :
find_package(LAPACK)
find_library(LAPACK_LIB liblapack.a lapack LAPACK_LIBRARIES PATHS ~/lib REQUIRED)

When you do the conda build of your package, does it produce any warnings/errors? Do you include the conda-forge channel? How are you trying to install the conda built package after you've made it? Could you just generally include some more of your workflow?

So when you run conda-build, you do get a package, but the dependencies are not included in your env. I tried to install directly the tarball generated by conda build, but it did not include the dependencies either.
However, it seems that the full install through conda forge does work and come with the requirements ! :/
